# How can I call smart Contract function from server side using ethereum account

Tags: ethereumjs

I want to call Smart Contract function from server side. 
How can I call?
I want to use nodejs.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can call. Use web3js or ethjs. I hope your smart contract is deployed in some eth network. If not then read below links for how to create smart contract and integrate with web3js.

- [Solidity Doc's](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/)
- [Geth Installation](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Building-Ethereum)
- [Web3JS](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Then can I create a new account which has a new secret key using web3JS?

Comment: @JiroYamamoto Yes: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50239320/3151675

Answer (score 0):

For your code, you'll want to look at [web3.js](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js) or [ethjs](https://github.com/ethjs/ethjs).  To actually access the network you'll need an Ethereum client node like [geth](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum) or [parity](https://github.com/paritytech/parity), or if you want to keep things simpler/web-servicey you can use a provider like [Infura](https://github.com/ethjs/ethjs).

Answer (score 0):

Any interaction with ethereum smart contracts happens through an ethereum transaction. contract creation is a transaction, contract invocation is a transaction. Transaction are signed with a private key, the signing process happens with the help of a software called "wallet". After the transaction is signed it must be broadcasted to the network. You broadcast a transaction by connecting to any ethereum node json-rpc interface and using the appropriate RPC call.

read more about this here; https://github.com/web3j/web3j & https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC

Answer (score 0):

There is a comprehensive answer about interaction between smart contract and Node-js at [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/79840/how-to-create-an-interaction-between-a-smart-contract-and-a-html-file-with-node/82405#82405) . I suggest read the question in first, after that, see the marked answer there.